# Image links with width and height

Tags: html

Source image:http://cdn2.supergoodmovies.com/FilesTwo/efb04e43d3e3471c86e406df449f75b8.jpg/151/99

i need to know how to make this type of links i.e, the width and height of the image can be changed by changing 151/99 in the link.please let me know what is the concept behind it.i am a beginner in this things so please give answer in detail.
Waiting for the answer.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What server side technology can you use?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the image width and hight trough the url extension. But this is only rescaling for the screen. Better is to interpret the url and resize the image on the server with image magick or other programs for image manipulation. But the important part here is the they have a rewrite url and interpret the url extension as get parameters. Those can be read by a php, asp, jsp whatever server application and trigger a process to either set the image attributes or resize an image with an additional programm on the server. The created image can then be sent as an image stream to the user.

Comment: Since ImageMagick is quite slow (but powerful) you should complement this with heavy caching of the images. Additionally, if you know that a certain size will be required more than others then you can pre-cache them before users reach your site.